# Tag inheritance in cucumber junit

Tags: java, cucumber, integration-testing, cucumber-junit

I am using cucumber for integration tests, and I need some launchers to run them. Launchers are pretty similar, the only difference should be tags. Lets say, I need three common tags and one unique for every launcher. Can I create a parent launcher contains all common cucumber options needed, and then extend it tags adding a unique tag in every child? How can I do that? Are `@CucumberOptions` inheritable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@CucumberOptions` are not inheritable in v5. There was some support for inheritance in older versions but not in a sensible way.